# Check for open ipv4 or ipv6 port

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

i was trying to make a port scanner with python and i want to check if a ipv6 port is open, ive been using the following code

```
port = 80
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))
except socket.error as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EADDRINUSE:
        print("Port in use")
```

i want to only bind ipv4 ports in this case but `socket.AF_INET` errors out even though port 80 is only open in ipv6

how can i make it so it only checks for ipv4 ports?

Comment: Why do you think port 80 is only open in ipv6?  My understanding is that many Linux platforms support dual stack (both ipv4 and ipv6) when an ipv6 port is bound, unless this functionality is explicitly disabled.

Comment: Trivial test to confirm: run the same thing for 8080 (or any other free port) and then look at netstat to see what ports are actually listening.

Comment: @FrankYellin i was listening on tcp6 port 80 using socat

Comment: Many platforms allow separate bindings for IPv4 and IPv6 on the same port. If the port is already bound to IPv6, binding the same port for IPv4 may succeed. If you want to check if a port is already being used for IPv6, then use an IPv6 socket for binding. `AF_INET` is for IPv4, `AF_INET6` is for IPv6